# data is not showing in dropdown template driven form

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

there is a template-driven form and within this form, there is a dropdown. I want to show data from the backend to the dropdown.

Here data is coming from the backend in `appliesWhenData`.

```
<form #appliesWhen="ngForm">
        <section class="form-inline" *ngFor="let awhen of appliesWhenData; let i = index;">
          <div class="col-auto my-1">
            <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2 form-control">
              <option [ngValue]="" disabled >Select field</option>
              <option [ngValue]="f" *ngFor="let f of fieldList">{{f.displayName}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
</section>
</form>
```

and if I log `appliesWhenData` it will print:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "detailSrl": 5,
    "value": "123",
    "local_id": 1,
    "fieldListDetail": {
      "id": 5,
      "fieldName": "officeLocation",
      "displayName": "OfficeLocation"
    },
    "conditionListDetail": {
      "id": 1,
      "condition": "Equals"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "detailSrl": 5,
    "value": "321",
    "local_id": 2,
    "fieldListDetail": {
      "id": 3,
      "fieldName": "productType",
      "displayName": "ProductType"
    },
    "conditionListDetail": {
      "id": 4,
      "condition": "LessThanEquals"
    }
  }
]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
<form #appliesWhen="ngForm">
        <section class="form-inline" *ngFor="let awhen of appliesWhenData; let i = index;">
          <div class="col-auto my-1">
            <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2 form-control" [(ngModel)]="awhen.fieldListDetail" name="fieldName{{ awhen.id }}">
              <option [ngValue]="" disabled >Select field</option>
              <option [ngValue]="f" *ngFor="let f of fieldList">{{f.displayName}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
</section>
</form>
```

Only I need to show selected data in drop. The selected data coming from backend is in `appliesWhenData.fieldListDetail` and the list which will be there is `fieldList`.
Please help!

Comment: You are using *ngFor="let f of fieldList". What kind of data is there in fieldList.

Comment: Can you tell what are the options and value need to use from that response?

Comment: @RK001 actually, is a dropdown so the user can update the data. first, it will show selected data which is in `appliesWhenData` and the list is in `field list`.

Comment: @sankasanjeewa sorry didn't get your question.

Comment: @SandeepKumar should `*ngFor="let f of fieldList"` it should be `*ngFor="let f of fieldListDetail"` as per the log you have printed and more over fieldListDetail should be a type of array i guess

Answer (score 0):

> Please try binding data like this:

```
          <option [ngValue]="f" *ngFor="let f of fieldList">{{f.fieldListDetail.displayName}}
          </option>
```